# What is the purpose of flag --webpack=react in rails react application?

Tags: reactjs, ruby, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I was learning about integrating ROR backend API with React frontend, I came across a flag introduced in Rails 5.1 which is:

```
--webpack=react
```

**Case 1:** When we don't use the flag

```
rails new myapp -d=mysql -T
```

**Case 2:** When we use the flag

```
rails new myapp --webpack=react -d=mysql -T
```

Can you please walk me through its usage and what happens when we do/don't add it in our Rails-React app?

How project files and code compilation gonna affect with it?

Comment: There's a number of options `rails new` takes to generate an application base that matches your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean `--webpack=react` used with `rails new` command:

```
rails new myapp --webpack=react
```

It creates new rails application and prepares webpack with react yarn dependencies for for you. Support for this command is added via webpacker gem, see [documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/5-x-stable/docs/integrations.md#react) for more info.

Comment: What exactly does it add? I don't see any react-related package included in to package.json file. I don't even get yarn.lock file created with --webpack-react flag.

Not sure what's going on...